# ansible - add 1 to ip address variable using ipmath

Tags: ansible, ip-address

This seems like it should be fairly straightforward.  I have a variable I defined in default.yml that I'd like to increment by one:

```
start_ip: 10.10.10.10
```

Then I set the fact and report it:

```
- set_fact:
    repo_ip:  "{{ start_ip|ipmath(1) }}"

- debug:
   msg: "repo_ip is {{ repo_ip }}"
```

I've also tried:

```
 - set_fact:
       repo_ip:  "{{ start_ip }}|ipmath(1)"
```

with the same result:

```
repo_ip is 10.10.10.10|ipmath(1)
```

Of course what I want is 10.10.10.11.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it should work as written in your first example. The second one is wrong, obviously, as the filter only works if inside the curly braces.

```
    - hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    start_ip: 10.10.10.10

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        next_ip: "{{ start_ip|ipmath(1) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "Next ip of {{ start_ip }} is: {{ next_ip }}"
```

This returns what you wanted.

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Next ip of 10.10.10.10 is: 10.10.10.11"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ansible.netcommon.ipmath(5)` instead of `ipmath(1)`

Also, you're missing the second set of double quotes in all your examples

Comment: Thanks for catching my lack of double quotes - I fixed that.

Tried above and I end up with "10.10.10.10|ansible.netcommon.ipmath(5) in my sources.list file.